# Getting cookie information from chrome extension

Tags: cookies, google-chrome-extension

I've tried to look this up but nothing really helped me. I have created a chrome extension and I need to check a cookie value from a given site.
this is my manifest file:

```
{
  "name": "MyExtension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "First version of My Extension",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "bmark.ico",
    "popup": "extension.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "cookies",
    "http://www.example.com"
  ]
}
```

in my html file this is my code:

```
chrome.cookies.get({ url: "http://www.example.com", name: 'user' }, function (cookie) {
                    alert(cookie != null);
                });
```

the result is false (my cookie is null). according to the google API that means that there isn't such a cookie BUT.... when I look in chrome to see my cookies (chrome://settings/cookies) I can see the cookie I was looking for. Any one knows why the chrome.cookies.get function doesn't work for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, i figured it out. i was missing the following permissions in the manifest.json file:

```
"http://*/*",
"https://*/*"
```

apparently they are needed to access the cookies.